# How can I make catching exceptions assign a variable a certain value without constantly repeating the code?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm going to clarify.

I'm logging 6 different variables and some of them have errors (what kind of error doesn't matter). When that error occurs, I just want that specific variable to be put to "NA".

Here's an idea of what I mean:

```
myDict = []
for i in data:
    try:
        eye = ...
        nose = ...
        mouth = ...
        ear = ...
        hair = ...
        tongue = ...
        
        myDict.append([eye, nose, mouth, ear, hair, tongue])

   except eye:
        eye = "NA"
        myDict.append([eye, nose, mouth, ear, hair, tongue])
  
   except nose:
        nose = "NA"
        myDict.append([eye, nose, mouth, ear, hair, tongue])

   except mouth:
        mouth = "NA"
        myDict.append([eye, nose, mouth, ear, hair, tongue])

   ...
```

Do I have to do an "except" for every single variable? Is there some way I could just do "except whatever variable has error, assign its value to "NA" and append normally"?

I also don't know what happens if there's an error in more than 1 variable.

The fundamental idea is: "if there's an error for a variable(S), just assign it/them the value "NA" and keep appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an approach that will do what you're asking.

First some comments:

- You have used the term "error", but your sample code uses try/except, so I will assume that each "error" results in an exception being raised.
- In the code below, I use an artificially simplified scenario in which the assignment to each variable has the possibility of raising an exception with a similar name, and I have created these as user-defined exceptions; in reality, you may not need to define these and would instead replace the parenthesized exception types in the sample code with the actual exceptions that you want to catch.
- You have something called `myDict` which is actually a python list; I will rename this `result` in the code below to avoid confusion.

The logic of the code below can be summarized as:

- Instead of assigning directly to named variables (as in the code in your question), iterate through a list of variable tags (strings like 'eye', 'nose', etc.) in an inner loop which has a try/except block inside it;
- Within this inner list, do the work for the given tag (the same work that would be done by `eye = ...` or `mouth = ...` in your question) and append the result to a list `L`, unless an exception is raised, in which case the try block instead appends "NA" to `L`;
- This means that whether or not there are errors (more accurately, whether or not exceptions are raised), `L` will have a value appended to it for each variable tag;
- At the end of the inner loop, append `L` to the result.

Here is the sample code:

```py
class eye_exception(Exception):
    pass
class nose_exception(Exception):
    pass
class mouth_exception(Exception):
    pass
class ear_exception(Exception):
    pass
class hair_exception(Exception):
    pass
class tongue_exception(Exception):
    pass


def getValueForEye(i):
    return "eye_value" + str(i)
def getValueForNose(i):
    return "nose_value" + str(i)
def getValueForMouth(i):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        raise mouth_exception()
    return "mouth_value" + str(i)
def getValueForEar(i):
    return "ear_value" + str(i)
def getValueForHair(i):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        raise hair_exception()
    return "hair_value" + str(i)
def getValueForTongue(i):
    return "tongue_value" + str(i)

data = [1, 2, 3]

result = []
for i in data:
    L = []
    for key in ['eye', 'nose', 'mouth', 'ear', 'hair', 'tongue']: 
        try:
            match key:
                case 'eye':
                     value = getValueForEye(i)
                case 'nose':
                     value = getValueForNose(i)
                case 'mouth':
                     value = getValueForMouth(i)
                case 'ear':
                     value = getValueForEar(i)
                case 'hair':
                     value = getValueForHair(i)
                case 'tongue':
                     value = getValueForTongue(i)
            L.append(value)
        except (eye_exception, nose_exception, mouth_exception, ear_exception, hair_exception, tongue_exception):
            L.append("NA")
    result.append(L)
```

Sample `result`:

```
['eye_value1', 'nose_value1', 'mouth_value1', 'ear_value1', 'NA', 'tongue_value1']
['eye_value2', 'nose_value2', 'mouth_value2', 'ear_value2', 'NA', 'tongue_value2']
['eye_value3', 'nose_value3', 'NA', 'ear_value3', 'hair_value3', 'tongue_value3']
```

---

Alternatively, if you are using a version of python that does not support the match/case construct, or you simply prefer not to use it, you can replace the loop above with this code which uses a dictionary to map from variable tag to function:

```py
funcDict = {
    'eye':getValueForEye, 
    'nose':getValueForNose, 
    'mouth':getValueForMouth, 
    'ear':getValueForEar, 
    'hair':getValueForHair, 
    'tongue':getValueForTongue
}
for i in data:
    L = []
    for key, func in funcDict.items(): 
        try:
            value = func(i)
            L.append(value)
        except (eye_exception, nose_exception, mouth_exception, ear_exception, hair_exception, tongue_exception):
            L.append("NA")
    result.append(L)
```